# How to get transactional logs from Azure application insights via code?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm quite new to Azure application insights and I've to verify a few events which are got logged in Azure insights in transactional logs, I was searching for resources, but couldn't get anything related to that. So how can get those logs via code?

Comment: You mean you found nothing... like... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/execute ? Always astonished how people claim long searches and do not find the documentation. AI has an api, you know. For anything SPECIFIC - you must ask a specific question. And please try something first.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by TomTom , you can use the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/execute) to Executes an Analytics query for data.

Below is the sample example for using POST with an Analytics query.

```
POST https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appId}/query
```

Alternatively, you can use this [application insights rest api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart) to build your custom solution wherein you can  Query and integrate with the performance, availability and usage data collected by Application Insights for your application